# Cannot enroll same fingerprint for multiple users

Tags: authentication, fingerprint-reader

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS Desktop, fresh install. I want to have multiple accounts on Ubuntu machine for different contexts, but when I try to add the same fingerprint on the second user I get an error.  If I try to do it with fprintd-enroll command, and I use the same finger, it says that it is a duplicate. I can register another finger for the new user though. Why is there unique constraint on fingerprints across user accounts? Is it possible to get around it?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS Desktop, sorry for ambiguous information.

Comment: use a different finger?